# UI library for XNA

Tags: c#, user-interface, xna, xbox360

I'm working on a small and simple XNA game and I'm noticing I'm spending way too much time implementing basic UI functionality like menus, (rich) text rendering including wrapping and basic UI lay-out such as alignment of elements.

This is a fairly common problem, and I was wondering whether anyone knows of a library to handle these things. I know there are some good skinnable options available to windows programmers (Crazy Eddie's GUI comes to mind), but as I'm targeting the Xbox 360 I would like to find a pure managed solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**xWinForms**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xwinforms/) is easily the most complete and actively maintained GUI system for XNA. [**Window System for XNA** (WSX)](http://wsx.codeplex.com/) had some good progress in the past (I was working on it for a while), and is still a decent system, though it hasn't been maintained for over a year now. The best option is definitely to go with xWinForms, at least until [WPF interoperability comes along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596/how-well-does-wpf-blend-with-xna-in-real-life) (next version of WPF/XNA?) and makes all the other options effectively obsolete.

Comment: Let's hope that the WPF interoperability thing comes and work smoothly. That would be a great addition.

Comment: xWinForms hasn't been updated since 2009 as of now. Seek other options.

Answer (score 5):

There's [XNA Simple Gui](http://www.codeplex.com/simplegui) and [xWinForms](http://www.ziggyware.com/news.php?readmore=374). They provide some basic GUI elements. Haven't seen any menu components, though.

Answer (score 5):

Check out SQUID:
http://www.ionstar.org/

It's a really clean, fast, and engine independent UI system. I've worked with it extensively and really enjoy using it. The download includes sample code for XNA 3.1, Truevision3D, and SlimDX.

Comment: You have no idea how much i was looking for something like this! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to recommend the [Nuclex Framework's GUI library](http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nuclex.UserInterface&referringTitle=Home).  Nuclex is great, active and fully tested.  It works on Windows and Xbox 360.  It also has a great design.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the projects listed here are now out of date.

The official thread for this question on the XNA forum is at http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/15274.aspx [link updated]

It's been kept up to date over the years by The ZMan.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Gamestate Management Example](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/samples/gamestatemanagement) for a game menu example.

NOTE: Last I checked, it wasn't fully functional with XNA 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

see FuchsGUI it's a light-weight GUI library

http://ghoshehsoft.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/xna-fuchsgui-part-i/

Answer (score 2):

I have once used this [Neoforce Controls](http://neoforce.codeplex.com/) library for one of my project.
Skin can be changed, and default Modern & Space-like UI skin may interest you.

Notice that this library is stated to not continue the development. Anyway you may find something useful there.

Note: as of June of this year, moved to GitHub here and resumed development:
https://github.com/NeoforceControls/XNA

Answer (score 0):

Adding Nuclear Winter to this list: https://bitbucket.org/sparklinlabs/nuclearwinter/

It's a stylish looking GUI and was built with touch input in mind.

Comment: repository deleted.. :-(